# $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Exhibit an isomorphism of the additive groups $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

i know $\mathbb{Z}_{6} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} = \{(0;0),(0;1),(0;2),(1;0),(1;1),(1;2)\}$. But how can I construct an isomorphism of these groups? I need help for this problem. Thank all!

Comment: Can you find an element of order 6 in $\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/3$

Comment: Map an element with order $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ into an element with order $6$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$. They both are cyclic groups with order $6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\phi:{\Bbb Z}_6\rightarrow{\Bbb Z}_2\times {\Bbb Z}_3:x\mapsto (x\;{\rm mod}\;2,x\;{\rm mod}\;3)$.

Comment: One direction of the bijection uses Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes, but this particular case is small enough to do by hand.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more general result which says:

given $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $gcd(n,m)=1$ then $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{nm}$. You can prove this by using the map

$\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{nm} \to \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ via
$x \to (x mod n, x mod m)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general , for each abel group whose order is $p_{1}p_{2}...p_{k}$ here $p_{1},p_{2},...p_{k}$ are $k$ distinct primes . Then $A$ is a cyclic group and

$$A \cong \mathrm{Z}/p_{1}p_{2}...p_{k} \cong \prod_{i=1}^{k} \mathrm{Z}/p_{i}$$

To prove this theorem you have to know following lemma , for each abelian group $A$ and prime $p$ denote $A(p)$ is subgroup which contains all elements of order $p^{t}$ for some $t \in \mathrm{N}$ .

Lemma : Assume $A$ is abelian group of order $p_{1}^{t_{1}}...p_{k}^{t_{k}}$ then :

$$A = \prod_{i=1}^{k}A(p_{i})$$

More , you can verify that order of $A(p_{i})$ is $p_{i}^{t_{i}}$

Now I use this lemma to prove theorem above . The first we have : $A = \prod_{i=1}^{k}A(p_{i})$ , each subgroup $A(p_{i})$ has order $p_{i}$ so it's a cyclic group $\mathrm{=>} \mathrm{Z}/p_{i} \cong A(p_{i})$ . Group $\mathrm{Z}/p_{1}p_{2}...p_{k}$ is also an abelian group whose order is equal with order of $A$ $\mathrm{=>} Q.E.D$

Back to your problem . I think it's a trivial check , nothing more . The proof of lemma above can be easy to find on Internet or if you're familiar with Sylow-group  .

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ and $H$ are finite groups and $(g,h)\in G\times H$ then $|(g,h)|=lcm (|g|,|h|)$. So if $G$ and $H$ are cyclic and of coprime order there is an element $g\in G$ and $h\in H$ with $|h|=|H|$ and $|g|=|G|$. It follows that $|(g,h)|=lcm(|G|,|H|)=|G||H|=|GH|$, so $GH$ is cyclic.